# Plotting points extracted from a .txt file in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to create a plot extracting points from a .txt file. The points are separated by 'tab' space only. Also, there are too many points to be accommodated in only one column, so they have been spread over 3 columns. However, when I plot in matplotlib, I am a little suspicious I am not seeing all the numbers plotted. It may be the case the data is plotted only over the first column and is ignoring the other two columns.

Here is the sample example of such data file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/th6uwrk2xdnmhyi/n1l2m2.txt?dl=0

I also attached the simple code I am using to plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import sys
import os
import numpy

from pylab import *

exp_sum = '/home/trina/Downloads/n1l2m2.txt'

a= numpy.loadtxt(exp_sum, unpack =True)


plt.plot(a)

show()
```

and[image] here is the output image:

I am interested to know if this plot covers all the points in my data file. Your suggestion is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `plt.plot(a)`, you are passing a 3 dimensional data set to be plotted onto a 2 dimensional graph.

From the matplotlib [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) for `plot`

> If x and/or y is 2-dimensional, then the corresponding columns will be
>   plotted.

So, your graph output is:

- column 0 values at x = 0
- column 1 values at x = 1
- column 2 values at x = 2

Adding the following to the code:

```
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    print('a'+str(i),max(a[i]),min(a[i]))
```

Outputs the following:

```
stats max min
a0 0.9999 0.0
a1 0.9856736 0.3736717
a2 -0.003469009 -0.08896232
```

Using the mouseover position readout with matplotlib, this looks correct.

On a general graphs point, I'd recommend using histograms, boxplots or violin plots if you want to visualise the frequency (and other stats) of data sets. See the matplotlib examples for [histograms](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_histtypes.html), [boxplots and violin plots](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/boxplot_vs_violin_demo.html).

Edit: from the shading on the graph you have, it also looks like it does contain all the points, as your data columns are long tails when plotted individually. The long tail graphs correlate to the shading on the graph you have.